# MOC (Meta-Object Compiler) in my Qt project where it's reporting an incorrect file name extension for a header file

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qt5, moc

Moc compiler throws this error when I run qmake.

`home/user/workspace/project/include/data.hp:78: Parse error at ...`

Interesting point, error line is correct. so just wrong thing that was reporting above path.

Actual path:
`/home/user/workspace/project/include/data.hpp`

1. I have double-checked that the file is named "data.hpp" and not "data.hp"
2. I have confirmed that the include path is correctly specified to include the "include" directory.
3. All include statements in my code use the correct relative path to "data.hpp"

I have solved (Parse) error, and project compiled successfully but i didn't understand why did say like that(path)?

**NOTES:**
qmake 3.1,
Qt 5.15.2